# Jquery function strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, placeholder

I found following function to enable placeholder like effect on browsers like IE6-9.
The problem is placeholder appears after first-time focusing. There is no initial value. Input boxes are just blank after page loading.

And another thing is, as on tutorial I created .placeholder class and set color to grey. It sets inputs color to light grey and doesn't change to black while user types.

```
var isInputSupported = 'placeholder' in document.createElement('input');
    var isTextareaSupported = 'placeholder' in document.createElement('textarea');
    if (!isInputSupported || !isTextareaSupported) {
        $('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder') && input.data('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
                input.removeClass('placeholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == '') {
                input.addClass('placeholder');
                input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
                input.data('placeholder', true);
            } else {
                input.data('placeholder', false);
            }
        }).blur().parents('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder') && input.data('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                }
            })
        });
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use focus for that when ready.

Comment: That code makes no attempt whatsoever to initialize input fields on page load. That's why it doesn't happen.

Comment: The code looks like it _should_ work - can you provide some context, where it doesn't work? Maybe a JSFiddle with the bug?

Comment: @Pointy it does, it calls `.blur()` on all matched elements which will initialize the placeholder when there is an empty value.

Comment: Yeah it looks like that code is firing before the elements exist. Make sure your Javascript is at the bottom of the page, or in a `$(document).ready()` handler.

Comment: @S.B. oops - commenting before coffee again :)

Comment: @S.B. please open page that I provided on IE8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address the problem of the placeholders not showing up initially, you need to initialize each of them when the page loads, something like this:

```
$('[placeholder]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val() == ''){
        $this.val($this.data('placeholder')).addClass('placeholder');
    }
});
```

The problem with the text color is that the `.placeholder` class is being added/removed on focus or blur, not when the user types. You need an additional event handler for keyup that removes the `.placeholder` class (this also includes my snippet from above):

```
var isInputSupported = 'placeholder' in document.createElement('input');
var isTextareaSupported = 'placeholder' in document.createElement('textarea');
if (!isInputSupported || !isTextareaSupported) {
     $('[placeholder]').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.val() == ''){
        $this.val($this.data('placeholder')).addClass('placeholder');
        }
    });
    $('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder') && input.data('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
            input.removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    }).on('keyup', function(){
            $(this).removeClass('placeholder')
    }).blur(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == '') {
            input.addClass('placeholder');
            input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
            input.data('placeholder', true);
        } else {
            input.data('placeholder', false);
        }
    }).blur().parents('form').submit(function () {
        $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder') && input.data('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: can you please add this function with full code? I'm not sure where to add this code piece

Comment: Huh, but how can you type in a textarea without focusing it first?

Comment: You can't type in a textarea without focusing in it first, however, this code is only removing the `placeholder` class if the value of the textarea/input is the same as the placeholder text

Comment: @S.B. have you found problem on page? I opened website on IE8.

Comment: @heron move the script to the end of the `<body>`

Comment: @Pointy it's already on the end. Please open link that I provided under question

Comment: Or wrap it in `$(function(){ ...script goes here... });`

Comment: @S.B. have you taken a look? it's already in dom.ready function

Comment: I updated my answer which should resolve the initial values not being there.

Comment: Ah found problem:) not data("placeholder") but attr(...)

Comment: Yes, you are correct; I failed to look at your code and assumed you were using a 'data-placeholder' attribute.